# Listener to label change

Tags: java, swt, label, listener

I created a `listener` to a `label` , that opens a new shell when the `label` is clicked, the `label text` change in every couple of milliseconds and I want a `listener` for the `label text` change .

Is it possible ?

I'm trying to display the values of the label on a graph in the new shell .

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see if it helps:

```
ModifyListener listener = new ModifyListener() {
    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
        // Handle event
    }
});

text1.addModifyListener(listener);
text2.addModifyListener(listener);
```

Comment: JTextField is in swing isn't it?
im using swt

Comment: ys, you are right, i did not read the tags. can you make it work by changing JTextField to Text

Comment: Still not working - i get an error :
The method addPropertyChangeListener(String, PropertyChangeListener) is undefined for the type Text

Comment: try ModifyListener http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/ntopic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/events/ModifyListener.html